# How to get count of another table in a left join

Tags: sql, database, mysql

I have multiple tables

```
post
    id  Name
    1   post-name1
    2   post-name2

user
    id  username
    1   user1
    2   user2

post_user
    post_id   user_id
    1         1
    2         1

post_comments
    post_id   comment_id
    1         1
    1         2
    1         3
```

I am using a query like this:

```
SELECT post.id, post.title, user.id AS uid, username
FROM `post`
LEFT JOIN post_user ON post.id = post_user.post_id
LEFT JOIN user ON user.id = post_user.user_id
ORDER BY post_date DESC
```

It works as intended. However I would like the get the number of comments for each post too. So how can I modify the this query so I can get the count of comments.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
SELECT post.id, post.title, user.id AS uid, username, COALESCE(x.cnt,0) AS comment_count
FROM `post`
LEFT JOIN post_user ON post.id = post_user.post_id
LEFT JOIN user ON user.id = post_user.user_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT post_id, count(*) cnt FROM post_comments GROUP BY post_id) x ON post.id = x.post_id
ORDER BY post_date DESC
```

EDIT: made it an outer join in case there aren't any comments

EDIT2: Changed `IsNull` to `Coalesce`

Comment: Make sure you account for the instances where a post has zero comments. In your select list, use

, ISNULL(x.cnt, 0) AS comment_count

Comment: @MrGumbe - good point, thanks. I thought about it but wasn't sure what DB he was using, since ISNULL doesn't work on some DB's (i.e. with Oracle, you have to use NVL).

Comment: Works without the ISNULL function. MySQL says #1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'ISNULL'

Comment: @Sinan - Sorry, I went by MrGumbe's comment without verifying it. Coalesce should work according the documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce

Comment: This works great thanks. But out of curiosity whats the difference between using sub-select and the one wihout it in @~unutbu's example?

Comment: You're welcome :).  That's not really a subselect I'm using, it's called an inline view (http://www.dba-oracle.com/tips_oracle_inline_views.htm).  The advantage of using an inline view, as I did above, is that you can outer join to it. And I don't think ~ubuntu's query will work anyway because he/she is not using a group by, and the approach itself is flawed since you just want the number of comments per post_id, and you can't get that with his/her query.

Answer (score 4):

This edited version shows rows with no comments:

```
SELECT post.id, post.title, user.id AS uid, username, count(post_comments.comment_id) as comment_count
FROM `post`
LEFT JOIN post_user ON post.id = post_user.post_id
LEFT JOIN user ON user.id = post_user.user_id
LEFT JOIN post_comments ON post_comments.post_id = post.id
GROUP BY post.id
ORDER BY post_date DESC
```

For example:

```
+----+------------+------+----------+---------------+
| id | title      | uid  | username | comment_count |
+----+------------+------+----------+---------------+
|  3 | post-name3 |    2 | user2    |             0 | 
|  1 | post-name1 |    1 | user1    |             3 | 
|  2 | post-name2 |    1 | user1    |             1 | 
+----+------------+------+----------+---------------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: @Sinan - see my answer, it handles that case.