# SQL - How to get counts from other tables during SELECT

Tags: sql-server

I've looked around for an existing answer, but from my understanding, there isn't a match (there might be, but the terminology/method doesn't make sense so I skip it).

Scenario:
I have 3 tables:

- Members,
- ActivityStart,
- ActivityComplete

The `Members` table has member profile information

The `ActivityStart` table records an entry whenever a member starts and activity, giving it a unique activity code and records the member's ID along with a timestamp.

The `ActivityComplete` table records the same information, but as an exit for the activity with the member's ID and timestamp - but this table also has a status field, for a full or partial complete.

What I need to do is export the member profile data along with a count of how many times they are in the Start table and how many times they are in the Exit table as a partial complete and how many times as a full complete.

So obviously I start with the basic query of

```
SELECT MemberID, FNAME, EMAIL FROM Members
```

But I am stuck how I'd even start to incorporate getting the counts from the other tables based on the MemberID for each record.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

I am using SQL2012.

Comment: Have you tried     GROUP BY

Comment: I think you want something like `WHERE (Select count(*) FROM ActivityStart) > 120`. It's an example, it means you want only Members that have an activity more than 120. OFC, you have to join the tables

Comment: please provide a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) for all your SQL related questions. That will help you getting answers quickly.

Comment: I have found this question that might be along the lines of what I need. This question seems to be selecting member details, and then getting the count of the number of posts from another table:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959702/how-to-get-count-of-another-table-in-a-left-join

I just need to understand the Coalesce function as I haven't come across that before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do it something like this:

```
  SELECT MemberID, FNAME, EMAIL ,
  (select COUNT (*) from ActivityStart start where start.MemberID=m.MemberID) ActivityStartCount,
  (select COUNT (*) from ActivityComplete  compl where compl.MemberID=m.MemberID) ActivityCompleteCount
FROM Members m
```

Comment: I just tested this in SSMS and it works.  Now to incorporate into my C# application and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
SELECT M.MemberID, FNAME, EMAIL, 
    StartCount = SUM(CASE WHEN Ast.ID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    FullCompleteCount = SUM(CASE WHEN AComp.ID IS NOT NULL AND AComp.Complete = 'Full' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    PartialCompleteCount = SUM(CASE WHEN AComp.ID IS NOT NULL AND AComp.Complete = 'Partial' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
FROM Members M
    LEFT JOIN ActivityStart ASt ON A.MemberID = M.MemberID
    LEFT JOIN ActivityComplete AComp ON AComp.MemberID = M.MemberID 
GROUP BY 
    M.MemberID, FNAME, EMAIL
```